# spring securityのログインページ作成で、デフォルトのページがでてきてしまう

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-security

現在springboot, gradle, spring securityでログインページを作っています。
thymeleafにてhtmlのloginForm.htmlを表示させたいのですが、
localホストでＵＲＬに何を入力しても/loginに飛ばされ、
spring securityのデフォルトログインページ(添付したスクショ)が表示されてしまします。
類似質問に http.httpBasic().disable();を足したら、とあったので実行しましたが駄目でした。
どうぞご教示お願いします。

> buildgradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    // springsecurityを依存関係に追加
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    // thymeleaf拡張ライブラリを依存関係に追加
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
}
```

> SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //  ハッシュアルゴリズム
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

//       http.httpBasic().disable();

        // 認可の設定
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/loginForm").permitAll() // loginFormは全ユーザーからアクセス可能
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN") //ADMINユーザーのみ
                .anyRequest().authenticated(); // 許可した項目以外は認証を求める

        //  ログイン処理
        http.formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login") //ログイン処理のパス
                .loginPage("/loginForm") //ログインページの指定
                .usernameParameter("email") //ログインページのメールアドレス
                .passwordParameter("password") //ログインページのパスワード
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true) //ログイン成功時のパス
                .failureUrl("/loginForm?error"); //ログイン失敗時のパス
}
```

> loginController

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/loginForm")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "loginForm";
    }
}
```

[image: 表示されるデフォルトページの写真]

Comment: [質問文に記載されているコード](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/jaso72859)をこちらの環境でも動かしてみましたが、想定通り動いているように見えます。おそらく、クラスのパッケージ等、質問文に表れていない箇所の問題ではないかと考えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。もう一度作り直してみたらできました！原因がわからずじまいだったのですが、とりあえず、このコード自体は合っているとわかったので、試行錯誤せずにすみました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

原因はわからなかったのですが、作り直して自己解決しました。ありがとうございます。